# Yaakov Avinu Talking About Eretz Yisroel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, avot-patriarch-fathers, lashon-hara-slander, famine

Since it is [forbidden](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76044/13811) to speak badly about Eretz Yisroel, was it considered lashon hara for Yaakov Avinu to tell Pharaoh that he had to leave the Holy Land because it was negatively impacted by famine [(Bereishis 47:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0)?

וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֶל־פַּרְעֹה לָגוּר בָּאָרֶץ בָּאנוּ כִּי־אֵין מִרְעֶה לַצֹּאן אֲשֶׁר לַעֲבָדֶיך**ָ כִּי־כָבֵד הָרָעָב בְּאֶרֶץ כְּנָעַן** וְעַתָּה יֵשְׁבוּ־נָא עֲבָדֶיךָ בְּאֶרֶץ גֹּשֶׁן -
We have come,” they told Pharaoh, “to sojourn in this land, for there is no pasture for your servants’ flocks, **the famine being severe in the land of Canaan.** Pray, then, let your servants stay in the region of Goshen.”

(Perhaps Yaakov Avinu could have said that the *global* famine forced them to turn to Egypt, or remove this line entirely.)

Comment: Facts and badmouthing are two different things.

Comment: "land of Cana'an" might be the key